# Audio to affect Material noise / texture values

Tags: materials, node-editor, animation-nodes, audio

I am attempting to make a procedural material and have audio files affect different elements of the material. Examples..

I would like to have audio.01 to animate the scale of a noise texture node.

I would like audio.02 to animate the rotation of another noise texture that is mixed in.

I would like audio.03 to animate the depth of the displacement.

Been watching videos and having the hardest time finding the best way to do this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the Shader Editor, with your mouse over the value you want to
   animate press I.
2. With your object selected open a Graph Editor and
   expand the options (left) until you see your keyframe and select it.
3. With your mouse still over the graph open the tool menu. (Either
   Space, or F3 depending on your settings) and type Bake Sound, you
   will see the option I posted. Click that, locate your sound file and
   play with the options on the left.

It will replace your keyframe with a curve that you cannot edit after baking, if you want to change it, you'll have to bake again.